# AWS Lambda: How to extract attachment (xls) from raw email?

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have raw emails in an S3 bucket. I'm writing an AWS Lambda function to extract the .xls attachment and save it to another S3 bucket. So far I have Lambda read the raw body of the email, but how do I extract the attachment?

```
s3.getObject({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: sesNotification.mail.messageId
    }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
            context.fail();
        } else {
            console.log("Raw email:\n" + data.Body);

            // Extract xls and copy to bucket

            context.succeed();
        }
    });
```

Attachment in email body:

```
------=_Part_3703880_1038025051.1459895117742
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Book1.xlsx
Content-ID: <223412a-63b2-9471-19a8-f94640ef04a5@yahoo.com>

UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQDIo800dgEAAAQFAAATAN0BW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCi2QEooAAC
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Answer (score -1):

the attachment is also in raw data so you need a way to "transfer" or decode that into the actual file contents that you can process.

Take a look at the python core library "email" for more details.